# When does an indexing company have to announce its re-balance/reconstitution dates?

Tags: etf, stock-exchanges, market-indexes

Every year indexes like the Russell cause huge volume days when they change the composition of their highly followed indexes.  Is there regulation that dictates the timing of when they announce what those days will be every year?

Answer (score 2):

Each index is run by a corporation. They decide on their own how often they change the makeup, and how they determine when and what changes have to be made.

There is no law, because these aren't government run. Only through tradition and the desire for a benchmark are these used.